# How would I solve this?

Tags: python

I have this Problem: 
Olaf the artificer makes and sells intricate decorations. Recently, he has been making baubles to
hang on Christmas trees.
Baubles come in two colours: red and blue. In his workshop, Olaf has RO red baubles and BO
blue baubles. Additionally, Olaf has S spare unpainted baubles, which he can turn into baubles of
either colour. Olaf cannot turn a red bauble into a blue bauble, or vice versa.
The royal palace just placed an order for RP red baubles and BP blue baubles.
Unfortunately for Olaf, the Goblin King has hired you to stop Olaf from being able to fulfil
this order! In the night, you will sneak into Olaf’s workshop and destroy some of his baubles, so
that Olaf cannot make up the order, no matter how he chooses to paint his spare baubles.
Olaf may wake up at any moment, so you will need to work quickly and efficiently. What is
the fewest baubles you can destroy to stop Olaf from fulfilling this order?\ how would I solve it?

ive tried:
`

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(9999999)
import random
DEBUG = True
#----------------------------------------------------
fin = open('baublesin.txt', 'r')
fin = fin.read()
if DEBUG: print(fin)
fin = fin.split(' ')
red = int(fin[0])
if DEBUG: print(red)
blu = int(fin[1])
if DEBUG: print(blu)
spa = int(fin[2])
if DEBUG: print(spa)
ore = int(fin[3])
if DEBUG: print(ore)
obl = int(fin[4])
if DEBUG: print(obl)
total = red + blu + spa
if DEBUG: print(total)
#----------------------------------------------------
# red - red_broken + ore + spa < red
# blu - blu_broken + obl + spa < blu
#
def check():
    if red - red_broken + ore + spa < red:
        if blu - blu_broken + obl + spa < blu:
            return True #if all the conditions are met, the problem is solved
    if blu - blu_broken + obl + spa < blu:
        if red - red_broken + ore + spa < red:
            return True # ''
    return False

red_broken = random.randrange(0, total, 1)
blu_broken = random.randrange(0, total, 1)
d = 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 #dont even question
a = 0
while a <= 300000: #should be enough
    red_broken = random.randrange(0, total, 1)
    blu_broken = random.randrange(0, total, 1)
    if check():
        if red_broken+blu_broken < d:
            d = red_broken+blu_broken
    a = a+1
#rn, the problem should be solved
print('done:')
print(d)
open('baublesout.txt', 'w').write(str(broken_red+broken_blu))
```

`

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. What have you already tried? See [ask] and [Asking about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/4518341)

Comment: i just added it now @wjandrea

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. What have you already tried, and how has it not worked? What specifically do you need help with? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Pol whats the format of the information in baublesin.txt ??

Comment: 4 2 1 2 2 as UTF-8 text

Comment: it is a python problem

Comment: why are you using `random.randrange()` instead of using math to find the minimum ? a random number generator will not work for finding the minimum.

Comment: how would I do that tho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly speaking this is far more a math problem than a python problem (one which you seem to have approached very inefficiently). Lets look at what information we have -

- RO red baubles
- BO blue baubles
- S spare baubles
- RP requested red baubles
- RB requested blue baubles

You just need to check for one edge case (so you don't end up breaking a negative number of baubles) This is just a concise function that gets the job done. It works by counting the minimum number spare baubles that need to be allotted to each color to find out the smallest number of baubles to break

```
def CalculateMinimumBroken(RO, BO, S, RP, BP):
    if max((RP - RO),0) + max((BP - BO),0) > S:
        return 0
    if RO > RP and BO > BP:
        return(S + min((RO-RP),(BO-BP)) + 1)

    return(S - max(0,(RP - RO)) - max(0,(BP - BO)) + 1)
```